# Account Linking Failed in facebook messenger platform using node.js

Tags: facebook, chat, bots, chatbot

Facebook messenger chat bot account linking process failed. I followed the process in [facebook account linking process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the unwanted ASCII characters, it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I fixed this error by subscribing to  the "messaging_account_linking" webhook event in the Facebook app settings.